# Generate sqlldr reject file with reject reason

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a `.csv` file with comma separated fields. Using `sqlldr` this file data will be uploaded into data base tables. And while loading if there is any `primary key` violated or `incorrect number` then the line will be written in `.bad` file and the reason will be written in `.log` file.

Example:

`Input file : 1,2,3,4,5,6
             2,3,4,5,6,7
             1,2,3,4,5,6`

When I load the above file data because of primary key violation line 3 will be written in `.bad` file

Example:
`Bad file: 1,2,3,4,5,6`

And log file will have

`SQL*Loader: Release...
Line 3: primary key violated...`

Can I write this error into `.bad` file itself i.e write error message at the end of each line??

Example:

`BAD file : 1,2,3,4,5,6, Line3: Primary key violated`

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you would want to do that even if it was possible.  The .bad file contains records only so this file could be renamed and reloaded after whatever issues that caused those records to get rejected was fixed.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005085):

```
The bad file is created in the same record and file format as the 
datafile so that you can reload the data after you correct it. For 
datafiles in stream record format, the record terminator that is found
in the datafile is also used in the bad file.
```